# What's really on the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, instance

If I have this code:

```
Label label1 = new Label();  
Form1.Controls.Add(label1);  
Label label2 = label1;
```

What's really on From1? Is it label1? Or is it the object label1 points to?

In other words if I then have this:

`Form1.Controls.Remove(label1);`

have I effectively removed the label? Or is label2 keeping it on the form?

I guess I'm wondering, is it the pointer that's on the Form, or is it the object the pointer points to?

Comment: I understand it is still kept alive, but is it still on Form1 by virtue of label2 still holding a reference to it?

Comment: sorry the asnwers below clarified it better than my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls.Add() adds a reference to whatever Control you pass to it. label2 = label1 just creates another reference to label1. Controls.Remove() doesn't delete the object, it just removes it from its list of controls.

So, in your example, after you call Controls.Remove():

- label1 would still "exist" (i.e. it will not be garbage collected).
- label2 would reference label1.
- The label would not still be part of the form because the form's list of controls no longer contains a reference to the label.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it will remove the `label1` from the `Form`. I would say that even the code like this

`Form1.Controls.Remove(label2)` will remove the label control from the `Form` as their both point on the *exactly* same UI object.

Comment: Ok so it's the object that gets added and removed from the Form.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: exactly. In `label1` and `label2` you hold a reference to it and by using them you can remove the *real* object form the form.

Answer (score 1):

`label1` and `label2` are merely variables containing a reference to the object. Both of them are referencing the same `Label` instance. When calling `Controls.Add`, the Controls collection also get a reference to the `Label` instance, and it may be rendered within the bounds of the `Form` (if it's visible and has coordinates that are withing the visible portion of the form, that is).

Comment: I got that part, but is it still on Form1 by virtue of label2 still holding a reference to it?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: yes, all of them (the Controls collection and the two label variables) are referencing the same object, but they are independent from each other. You can add and remove the label from the form without affecting the variables, and you can assign `null` to the variables without affecting the form.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the label object label1 references to the form, and just assigned another reference to it using label2. If you remove label1 from the form's control list, you've removed the form's reference to the label object, but label1 and label2 still point to the object hence the label object won't be garbage collected until they fall out of scope.